# Angular js number format comma

Tags: angular, numbers

I need to display number format as **Rs. 12,36,762.51**  but currently it is displaying as
**Rs. 1,236,762.51**

I need to change the format , this is how i am using in angular js

```
{{total | number:2}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below currency filter to show correct comma separated values.

```
{{total | currency:'INR'}}
```

You can make use of custom filter as well as shown below, here you can modify it as per your usage

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('totalController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.total = 12345678.00;
});

app.filter('IndiaCurrency', function () {        
    return function (input) {
        if (! isNaN(input)) {
            //var currencySymbol = '₹';
            var currencySymbol = 'Rs.';
            //separe fraction part        
            var result = input.toString().split('.');
            //separate last three digit
            var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
            var restNum = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
            if (restNum != '')
                lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
                //replace commas at places
            var output = restNum.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
            //handle 0 after franction
            if(result[1]==undefined) {
               result[1] = "00";
            } else if(result[1].length <2) {
               result[1] += "0";
            }
            if (result.length > 1) {
                output += "." + result[1] + "";
            }            
            //Return result with symbol
            return currencySymbol + output;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="totalController">
    <h3>{{total | IndiaCurrency}}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, you can specify the code and add the symbol {{ total | currency: "INR": "symbol"}} reference here: [Angular Currency Pipe & Format Currency In Angular with examples](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-currency-pipe-formatting-currency-in-angular/)

Comment: correct, thanks for sharing the link

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar  working fine but only one issue if the value is 15,23,111.50 it is displaying as 15,23,111.5 and if it is 15,23,111.00 it is displaying as 15,23,111 but I need fixed 2 digits

Comment: @vellaidurai, updated my code to handle `00`, please check now